# How to check if a certain word is contained in a text file?

Tags: java, file, text

I'm trying to check every occurrence of these words- **Calculate, EXE, I/O, Yield**, and **Out**. I read in a file and store the data in an object called process. All the data has been correctly stored in the object. The **Method** **prep** finds every occurrence of these words. The only problem is all the 
    words work except **I/O** the first occurrence never shows up.

**Code-**

```
 public void contentArray(Process x)
 {
     for(int i=0; i<x.getListInfo().size(); i++)
     {
         System.out.println(x.getindex(i));
     }
 }

 public void prep(Process x)
 {
     System.out.println("******************");
     String xo ="oo";
     while(xo!="EXE")
     {
         for(int i=0; i<x.getListInfo().size(); i++)
         {
             String processor = x.getindex(i);
             if(processor.equals("I/O"))
             {
                 System.out.println("I/O " + i );
                 xo="I/O";
             }
             else if(processor.equals("CALCULATE"))
             {
                 System.out.println("Calculate "+ i);
                 xo="CALCULATE";
             }
             else if(processor.equals("YIELD"))
             {
                 System.out.println("YIELD " + i);
                 xo="YIELD";
             }
             else if (processor.equals("OUT"))
             {
                 System.out.println("Out " + i);
                 xo="OUT";
             }
             else if (processor.equals("EXE"))
             {
                 System.out.println("EXE " + i);
                 xo="EXE";
             }
         }
     }
 }


import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class FileReader {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int fileNum = 0;
    String filename;
    int runtime = 0;
    int memory = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    String name = "";
    int filecounter = 0;
    String x = "";
    ArrayList<Process> allfiles = new ArrayList<Process>();
    System.out.println("How many files do you have");
    x = in.nextLine();
    while (filecounter < Integer.parseInt(x)) // number of files
    {
        System.out.println("enter file name");
        filename = in.nextLine();
        filecounter++;
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\documents\\git\\" + filename);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
        //Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (s.hasNext()) {// takes in all file values
            list.add(s.next());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).equals("Name:")) {
                name = list.get(i + 1);
                System.out.println(name);
                //list.remove(i);// removes name
                //list.remove(i+1);// removes file name
            }
            if (list.get(i).equals("runtime:")) {
                runtime = Integer.parseInt(list.get(i + 1));
                System.out.println(runtime);
                //list.remove(i); //removes runtime
                //list.remove(i+1); //removes runtime value
            }
            if (list.get(i).equals("Memory:")) {
                memory = Integer.parseInt(list.get(i + 1));
                System.out.println(memory);
                //list.remove(i);//removes memory
                //list.remove(i+1); //removes memory value
            }
        }
        counter++;//pid starts from 1 and goes up
        Process p = new Process(name, counter, runtime, memory, ProcessState.New, list);
        allfiles.add(p);



        s.close();




    }
    Scheduler schedulerQ = new Scheduler();
    schedulerQ.contentArray(allfiles.get(0));
    schedulerQ.prep(allfiles.get(0));


}
}
```

**Output-**

Input test file
  Name: lo 
  Total Runtime: 100
  Memory: 90

I/0 90
CALCULATE 80
I/O 90
CALCULATE 20
CALCULATE 100
CALCULATE 100
YIELD
YIELD 
OUT
EXE

**My Error**: the error occurs never takes in first I/O !!!!!!!!!!!

**Output from console:**
Calculate 9

I/O 11

Calculate 13

Calculate 15

Calculate 17

YIELD 19

YIELD 20

Out 21

EXE 22

Comment: Have you step debugged and checked the actual value of your processor object when you expect it to be "I/O"?

Comment: yes and the processor is gettin I/O but Its not executing if statement

Comment: Also if any help but only run into problems with I/O

Answer (score 0):

The input file seems to have I/0 in the first occurrence and not I/O. Could you check the input file again?